# Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Incorrect public key: error:04099079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error

Tags: php, encryption, rsa

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Incorrect public key: error:04099079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error in /home/apptestl/domains/apptestlab.pl/public_html/nextalk/zalogowano/crypto_library.php:13 

Stack trace: 
#0 home/apptestl/domains/apptestlab.pl/public_html/nextalk/zalogowano/send_message.php(33): encryptMessage('1', '-----BEGIN PUBL...') 
#1 {main} thrown in /home/apptestl/domains/apptestlab.pl/public_html/nextalk/zalogowano/crypto_library.php on line 13

in code (crypto_library.php -\> encryptMessage function):
```

```
@param string $message
 * @param string $publicKey
 * @return string
 */
function encryptMessage($message, $publicKey) {
    $public = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwcfUpZmZxTh5M4mS8OUC Ov+aEHmJu9WMeOp2k/NcEkspQ8WZRitHaSGoIp1dmFlQBqJKUQjm4Amu8hzmNLib IgL0Ihn+//fvA24z1BprEY6MkhYPx0UqP3m19yHpCxHb2fYGCK2QyIwUSnhpO0pW Hg4Y6ciCx5WHdfnD2jvT1Oz2mYHsUbLA9bc3F7QVbBnjYCmqqosz0WWZhDXoF4fi +6gnGe/DL0yxdZkyw8sBmipqAVv9b0hMspY7kkKW4XKQgqtwNXKmQUzEl0O3xh10 Az+AdEr1GrMkGqCJOd+TGp1u/KUZPE0tCKfUCFwKnAHSCoxPE5ERzwfXwTm3NqJ1 dQIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    $publicKeyResource = openssl_pkey_get_public($public);
    if (!$publicKeyResource) {
        throw new Exception('Incorrect public key: ' . openssl_error_string());
    }

    // openssl_public_encrypt($message, $encrypted, $publicKeyResource, OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
    openssl_public_encrypt($message, $encrypted, $publicKeyResource, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
    openssl_free_key($publicKeyResource);

    return base64_encode($encrypted);
}
```

code (send_message.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once("../db.php");
    require_once("crypto_library.php");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['message'], $_POST['message_to'], $_POST['chat_no'])) {
        $currentLogin = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $message = trim($_POST['message']);
        $messageTo = $_POST['message_to'];
        $chatNo = $_POST['chat_no'];
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password_db, $dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        if (empty($messageTo) || empty($chatNo)) {
            echo "All fields are required.";
            exit();
        } elseif (empty($message)) {
            echo "Empty message.";
            exit();
        }
        $receiverPublicKey = getPublicKey($messageTo);


        $encryptedMessage = encryptMessage($message, $receiverPublicKey);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (mess_from, mess_to, message, date, ip, chat_no) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $currentLogin, $messageTo, $encryptedMessage, $date, $userIP, $chatNo);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            echo 'success';
        } else {
            echo $stmt->error;
            // echo 'error';
        }

        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

please help me to fix this bug

Comment: For `openssl_pkey_get_public()` it's enough if there is a line break immediately *after* the header and immediately *before* the footer (the *exact* PEM encoding - as described in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77597090/9014097) - which would require adding the line breaks in the body after every 64 characters and removing the spaces, is not needed, which makes the fix a little easier, see this online demo: https://paiza.io/projects/mGA80Nh-Osibh7tPcHnu6Q).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is not formatted well as it lacks line endings. Those are required for the PEM format, as you can read [in the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-2). So you need to end the line after the header (that ends with the 5 dashes after the `BEGIN PUBLIC KEY` and after the 64th character on a line of base 64.

On the other hand, the spaces that are in the base64 definitely should not be there. Otherwise the public key seems to be formatted correctly.